# Powershell - Get-ChildItem and Join-Path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to query registry for the InstallLocation to a specific app, and then I'm looking to create a path based on that information.

For example, I am looking to find Microsoft Office Installation directory in the registry, and then get to Directory\Word.exe. The challenge is that the function "Join-Path" keeps returning a null value for the stored variable:

```
$ProgramName = "*Microsoft*Office*"
$results = Get-ChildItem 
"HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\*\Products\*\InstallProperties" | 
Where-Object { $_.getValue('DisplayName') -like $ProgramName } | ForEach-Object {   
$_.getValue('InstallLocation')} 
$childfolder = 'Office16'
Join-Path $results $childfolder
```

Error: Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
Also, when I dropped the Join-Path altogether and attempted to manually concatenate the strings, it appears a space was always added, even when I explicitly called the variables, which leads me to assume that PS is executing the command separately (Not actually concatenating them).

I'm assuming that I'm not storing the variable properly. Trying .ToString() caused the same error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Edit: Here's the behavior when I call $results and try to concatenate them:

```
$results
$Endpath = ($results) + ($childfolder)
$Endpath
```

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\

Office16

Comment: Maybe `InstallLocation` is empty for those keys.

Comment: When I toggle breakpoint, and/or call $results, I see the path successfully: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\

Comment: One of those `InstallLocation` values is empty. You need to filter out empty ones. --> `Where-Object { $_.getValue('DisplayName') -like $ProgramName -and $_.getValue('InstallLocation')}` or `join-path ($results |? {$_}) $childfolder`

Comment: Looks like that did it! I think I get it. The "extra spaces" were caused by null results that were added onto the non-null result, and I'm assuming that join-path doesn't like a path that ends with a space. Thanks much, I was pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

One of your `InstallLocation` values is empty. The error is thrown when one of the values bound to the `-Path` parameter of `Join-Path` is empty or `$null`. You need to filter out the empty values.

```
$ProgramName = "*Microsoft*Office*"
$childfolder = 'Office16'
$results = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\*\Products\*\InstallProperties" |
    Where {$_.DisplayName -like $ProgramName -and $_.InstallLocation}
if ($results) { Join-Path $results $childfolder }
```

`Where {$_.Property}` will evaluate to `True` if the property contains a non-empty and non-null value that would not normally evaluate to `False`.